# Calling functions from other functions in Azure servless function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have a timer function that runs by itself once per minute.

Is it possible to invoke this function from another type of function if I want to call it at an arbitrary time (not on its cron schedule).

From:

- An orchestrator function?
- An activity function?

Also, it is it possible to call an orchestrator directly from a an activity function? I have heard that you can do "sub orchestrations" from an orchestrator. But what about directly from an activity function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the Time Trigger Function, but one thing you can do is extract the logic to a class library and share it with a Http Trigger that function that will be running in the same Azure Function App as the time trigger one.

About the Durable part, it's been a while since the last time I worked with that, but as far as I know, the orchestrator can call sub orchestrators and activities.